# Is there some method to request newest postgresql postgis package rather than specific version?

Tags: apt, package-management, postgresql

There is `postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1` and there is `postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1`. Unfortunately 9.3 is available only on trusty and 9.4 is not available on trusty (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 and http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1).

So any installation instructions/script must include something along "if your OS version is...". Is there some method to simply install newest postgresql postgis package?

Comment: No simple method. There's no virtual package for the current version of `postgresql`-related packages. You could install `sudo apt-get install --install-suggests postgis`, which depends on these packages.